# Compare/check multiple columns in multiple sheets and find the unmatched values

Tags: libreoffice-calc, comparison

I have two sheets in libreoffice calc, both sheets have same columns, i need to compare these sheets column values(multiple columns) and need to check rows are equal, if not equal then need to differentiate the unmatched values.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Testing for matching is relatively straightforward.  Something like this in the top row to the right of the existing columns:

```
=IF(AND(A1='Sheet2'.A1;B1='Sheet2'.B1;C1='Sheet2'.C1);"match";"error")
```

Just keep adding arguments for however many columns you have to test, then copy & paste down however many rows you have.

I'm not sure of an elegant way to display the unmatched values.  You could of course have additional helper columns where each column is dedicated to being blank for a match in its corresponding source column and displaying the unmatched value if the corresponding source column doesn't match.